# SQL Server 2005 backup - view or restore without meddling with existing database?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 set up and I backed up a database a year ago, and now need a few views from it. Backup is rather large, 6GB, and the database is up and running 24/7 and I cannot meddle with it, I just need these views. Creating a new database "TEMP" and trying to restore to it gives me an error stating this is a backup of another database.

How can I get the data I need without detaching or corrupting the active database?

thank you

Comment: crossed my mind, but i am on a remote location via gprs, and this is rather urgent... thanks though. If red-gate software doesnt work, i'll rar to split volumes and dooownload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Red-Gate's [SQL Compare Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm), you can easily compare an existing database and a database backup file (`*.bak`) and extract some elements from the backup.

Red-Gate's [SQL Virual Restore](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Virtual_Restore/index.htm) allows you to "mount" a backup file like a live database - maybe that's more what you're looking for??

Answer (score 2):

You just don't want to do such things on a production server. It is just too risky.

Set up a temp server. 6GB is really not large, you can do this easily on your PC. Restore the dump there and extract the things you need.

HTH